# Dynamically load images from css using htaccess in subfolder

Tags: css, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am creating multiple website in my local webserver. I have trouble when loading images form a css files dynamically when using subfolders.

This is my structure:

```
Root folder
    site1
        index.php (loads templates using Smarty)
        .htaccess
        public_files
            css
            js
            img
            templates
```

This is how my .htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$             index.php?uri=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(css|js|img)/(.*)$       public_files/$1/$2 [L]
```

Loading my css does work:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

But within this css I cannot load images

```
background-image: url("img/background.jpg");
```

I think this is because this line is called from the css folder. But when I use `/img/...` it will look in the root, which is also not the right place because I'm within a subfolder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your `site1/.htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site1/

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public_files/ [NC]
RewriteRule (?:^|/)css/(img/.+)$ public_files/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public_files/ [NC]
RewriteRule (?:^|/)((?:css|js|img)/.+)$ public_files/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: This way even my css isn't loaded.

Comment: Can you open your page in Firebug and check the `Net tab` and then tell me what URL you get for css that generates 404 for you?

Comment: Now it also tries to open `http://localhost/site1/css/img/background.jpg` and it got a `Internal Server Error`

Comment: It is looking at `http://localhost/site1/css/img/background.jpg` so from the css folder.

Comment: Also I got the message: `Not found: /site1/public_files/css/img/background.jpg`

Comment: How is `/site1/public_files/css/img/background.jpg` returning 404 you will have to tell me since as per your question that is the directory structure you have. Was the original URI as `http://localhost/site1/css/img/background.jpg`? Should it not be: `http://localhost/site1/img/background.jpg`???

Comment: Original the file is located in `http://localhost/site1/public_files/img/background.jpg`. In my css located in `http://localhost/site1/public_files/css/main.css` I use `background-image: url("img/background.jpg");` and the current message is `Not found: /site1/public_files/css/img/background.jpg`. the img folder is not within the css folder :)

Answer (score 0):

`url("img/background.jpg")` says that img/ is *relative* to the directory holding the css (css/, I presume). So it could be looking in /css/img/. Try ../img/ instead.

Comment: Yes, that is the reason i use the `.htaccess` file. I don't want to change every path when I move my website to the root folder.